# Hide div unless class is X

Tags: jquery

If I have a a group of divs that look like this:

```
<div class="entry-container #sts01"></div>
<div class="entry-container"></div>
<div class="entry-container #sts01"></div>
<div class="entry-container #sts02"></div>
<div class="entry-container"></div>
<div class="entry-container #sts03"></div>
<div class="entry-container"></div>
<div class="entry-container #sts02"></div>
```

and I only want to show the divs that contain a certain #, something like:

```
$('.entry-container:contains(:not("#sts01"))').hide();
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

You can filter those elements using `not` and `class` selector

```js
$('.entry-container').hide().filter('.\\#sts01').show(); //you need to escape the `#` in the class name
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-container #sts01">1</div>
<div class="entry-container">0</div>
<div class="entry-container #sts01">1</div>
<div class="entry-container #sts02">2</div>
<div class="entry-container">0</div>
<div class="entry-container #sts03">3</div>
<div class="entry-container">0</div>
<div class="entry-container #sts02">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.entry-container').hide();//hide all
$('div[class^="#sts"]').show();//show only the elements whos class start(^) with `#sts`
```

or

```
$('.entry-container').not('[class^="#sts"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.entry-container').not('.sts01').hide();//hide all execpt class sts01
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-container sts01">1</div>
<div class="entry-container">2</div>
<div class="entry-container sts01">3</div>
<div class="entry-container sts02">4</div>
<div class="entry-container">5</div>
<div class="entry-container sts03">6</div>
<div class="entry-container">7</div>
<div class="entry-container sts02">8</div>
```

Select all class and use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the class you want to show

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

CSS class names starting with `#` [are not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/2333214) (*unless you go out of the way to escape them everywhere*). You should better use some other selector like [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes. Then you can easily select them using an attribute selector. For eg:

```js
$('.entry-container:not([data-value]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-container" data-value="#sts01"></div>
<div class="entry-container"></div>
<div class="entry-container" data-value="#sts02"></div>
```